# Can someone tell me if Andorid studio 3.0.1 has component tree view and if there is where can i enable it from?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is what i can see when i open android studios

[image]

I want to follow along with a few video tutorial but when ever they do anything with component tree i'm totally lost . I tried Shift + F12 to restore to default layout but thats not doing anything .

Comment: I also tried to change the PropertiesComponents and edit these lines

Comment: <property name="UI_DESIGNER_EDITOR_MODE.UIDesignerToolWindowManager2.WIDTH" value="1" />
<property name="UI_DESIGNER_EDITOR_MODE.UIDesignerToolWindowManager2.STATE" value="left" /> but its not even there

Comment: @Christopher Clicking on projects only opens the project folders . that was not what i was talking about . I was talking about component tree which usually comes on the right side  which shows the device screen tab/folder and the objects like textview and all under relative layout subdirectory .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the Text sub-tab of the layout editor, so you have the XML on the left and a preview on the right.

Click on the Design sub-tab (towards the lower-left corner of your screenshot) to bring up the graphical layout editor, with the Palette, Component Tree, and Attributes panes.

Comment: https://imgur.com/GB4gBRX    This is what comes when go to the design tab

Comment: @ParagJayaram: Click on the words "Component Tree", just above the Design sub-tab's actual tab, to display the component tree.

Comment: Holy moly . I cant believe i was so blind to that . Thank you soo much :D